# Assistance needed with drop down selection auto update using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a kind of pc builder however when using drop down lists, it isn't updating the price;

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{     
var total = 0; //Base price

function calcTotal() 
{ 
$("select").each(function() 
{ 
    //This happens for each checked input field 
    var cost = $(this).val(); //I beleive the problems are here and...
    total += parseInt(cost); //total = total + cost             
   }); 
}       

//This happens when the page loads 
calcTotal();     
$("form").before('<p class="total">Base Price of Your Custom PC: <strong>£' + total + '</strong></p>'); 
$(":submit").before('<p class="total">Base Price of Your Custom PC: <strong>£' + total + '</strong></p>'); 

$("input:checkbox, input:radio").click(function() //... and problem here?
{ 
    total = 0;  //Base price
    calcTotal(); 
    $("p.total").html("Total Cost of Your Custom PC: <strong>£" + total + "</strong>"); 
}); 

});
```

and my html here;

```
<head>
<title>Test - PC Builder</title>

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1")</script>
<script src="t.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="###" method="post">

Choose an Operating System
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="qty1">
<select name="productpr1">
<option value="Case A:10">---</option>
<option cost="25" value="Win 7:25">Win 7 (add £25)</option>
<option cost="50" value="Win 8:50">Win 8 (add £50)</option>
</select>
<br>
Choose a Case
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="qty2">
<select name="productpr2">
<option value="Case A:10">---</option>
<option cost="10" value="Case A:10">Case A (add £10)</option>
<option cost="15" value="Case B:15">Case B (add £15)</option>
</select>

        <!-- Send Button -->
        <input name="return" type="hidden" value="#">
        <input type="submit" value="Buy Now!">


    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using `cost=""` as the value to workout the calculation but when I load the html page I get `£NaN` for the value of the price? i cannot use the value attribute as this is used for another function.

Can anyone help?

See http://jsfiddle.net/T3T7v/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, separate answer because there's a lot going on here:

Firstly, you're trying to get the selected option from all the selects by using:

```
 $('select').each(function() {/*...*/});
```

Not gonna work. You should use [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

```
 $(':selected').each(function() {/*...*/});
```

Inside that you also need to handle the case where the selected option has not got a value (which is the default). I'd go with:

```
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 if(typeof id !== 'undefined')
 {
     total += parseInt(id, 10); // Note: always supply a base when using parseInt
 }
```

Although there's probably a neater way of doing it. Note also that you had `parseInt('id')`, which is wrong. You want to parse the value of the `id` variable, not the string `'id'`.

Finally, the line:

```
$('').change(function() //Error must be here?
```

Obviously needs to be:

```
$('select').change(function()
```

Overall, i'd probably change the structure somewhat too, but that's a story for another day. Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/T3T7v/12/

Comment: Ta very much, the is most helpful, i guessed there may have been a couple of obvious mistakes :) thank you for the     parseInt note.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the `cost` attribute, you should use `$(this).attr('cost')` instead of `$(this).val()` - see jQuery's [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1).

That said, cost is obviously not a valid html attribute. You should avoid using it. If you need to use a custom attribute, you should use `data-cost` - see [data-* attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

In the future it's probably worth debugging through your JS using a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the [Webkit Inspector](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector) and liberal use of [console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log) statements to narrow down your problem somewhat.

Comment: Hi, I've changes cost for id and amended this on the html and js file, however it doesn't auto update on the html, I'm guessing it's a problem here    $("input:checkbox, input:radio").click(function() instead on input:checkbox, input:radio. should this be select,selector or selection etc? you help is appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T3T7v/5/ - updated slightly. you'll see than the price is ment to auto update, but just shows £NaN i've annotated where i think the error may be.